# How do I find an end point with microsoft project hawaii's relay service? (Windows phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to make a multiplayer game for windows phone 7, I'm planning to use [Project Hawaii's relay system](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/download/HowToUseTheHawaiiRelayService.pdf) to send data between multiple phones. How do I find the endpoint of a particular phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong but from what I understand from the linked document is:
1. First you create an endpoint

```
Endpoint endpoint = new Endpoint("DeviceId", "RelayTestClient",TimeSpan.MaxValue);
```

1. Then according to the same document: "Creation of the Endpoint instance triggers a call to the Hawaii Relay service to register the endpoint."
2. Which then, you can contact from another device using:

   public SendMessageRequest(string to, byte[] data, TimeSpan timeToLive)

where "to" is "RelayTestClient" from the Enpoint instantization

1. When you're done:

   this.endpoint.Deregister();

I believe that for the devices to become aware of each other you would have to create/join a group first (with a name unique to you) and each time new device connects it sends information about itself to the group.